# Replacing a color with rmagick

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I'm currently stuck on a - more or less - simple task. I need to replace some colors with other colors in an image using rmagick.

I found two approaches.

- Looping through every pixel to replace it's color
- Color to alpha, set background color, save as new image.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer myself:

Using [Magick::Image#opaque_channel](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/Magick%2FImage:opaque_channel)

Comment: Thanks! ref: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/Magick%2FImage:opaque_channel